# SVG: Set background color only for area within a path

Tags: css, svg

I have a SVG and I would like to change the color of this svg when an action happens

Checkout this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lxx1gc2/2/)

The only thing that is not correct in this demo is the `red` color, because I only want the background color of the arrow to be red.

```
.highlight {
    background-color: #000;
}

.highlight svg g path {
    fill: #fff;
}

.highlight svg {
    background: red;
}
```

Is it possible to change the background color of the area within a path ?

Comment: The path is an outline it is the outer line of the arrow and then the inner line of the arrow. You would need to redraw the path so that it is a single line and use stroking to colour the arrow edge, filling will then colour the inside.